# Jquery: append first li child to the end of the list

Tags: jquery, html-lists, append

```
<ul>
<li>first children</li>
<li>second children</li>
<li>third children</li>
</ul>
```

How can I use Jquery to remove first children and append it to end of ul list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many methods than you can use, like `appendTo` method.

```
$('ul li:first').appendTo('ul')​​​​;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mb42Z/

or `insertAfter` method:

```
var $li = $('ul li');
$li.eq(0).insertAfter($li.last())
```

Note that element is moved and not removed.

- [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)
- [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)
- [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)
- [last](http://api.jquery.com/last/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var lis = $('ul li');
lis.first().insertAfter(lis.last())​​​​;
```